# Returning multiple values from SELECT nested within CASE

Tags: sql, nested, case

I'm trying to return multiple values in a single column which are linked to a position number (1 through 6), but only those values which are of a certain position in each case. Basically I have 6 columns I want to create, 1 for each position, and return all of the result values associated with that position number. I created 6 Nested Case statements to try to get these results:

```
(CASE WHEN tbl_TestWells.well_result <> NULL
THEN 
(SELECT tbl_TestWells.well_result
FROM tbl_TestWells
WHERE tbl_TestWells.Well_Index = 1)
ELSE NULL END) AS  Well_1_Graded_Result,
```

The problem is that they only return NULL values in the way it's set up. If I take out the case then I get the Error Message "subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

EDIT: The full code is part a view so I've simplified it to what's pertinent

```
SELECT DISTINCT
--Other Columns being selected

(CASE WHEN tbl_TestWells.well_result <> NULL
THEN 
(SELECT tbl_TestWells.well_result
FROM tbl_TestWells
WHERE tbl_TestWells.Well_Index = 1)
ELSE NULL END) AS  Well_1_Graded_Result,

--The other five well results are set up in the exact same format as above, just replacing 1 with the corresponding number

FROM tbl_TestCartridges

JOIN tbl_Tests ON
tbl_Tests.test_uid = tbl_TestCartridges.test_uid

JOIN tbl_Programs ON
tbl_Programs.program_uid = tbl_Tests.program_uid

JOIN tbl_Cartridges ON
tbl_Cartridges.system_uid = tbl_Programs.system_uid

JOIN tbl_TestWells ON
tbl_TestWells.test_cartridge_uid = tbl_TestCartridges.test_cartridge_uid

JOIN tbl_TestSamples ON
tbl_TestSamples.test_well_uid = tbl_TestWells.test_well_uid 

ORDER BY tbl_TestCartridges.barcode

;
```

Comment: Might be helpful to specifically note what variant of SQL (T-SQL, MySQL, PL/SQL) that you're using, since the ISNULL/IFNULL functions vary between them.

Answer (score 1):

A CASE statement can't be used to cause 6 rows to appear in place of one row.  You need to build your "1 or many rows" logic into the JOINs of your query, not the CASE statement.

Include your full query and schema, and an explanation of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Edited to show the rest of the code, as needed. What I'm trying to accomplish is to get 6 columns in the view, one for each of the six well positions, with it's associated well result. The well position number and the result are both found in Tbl_TestWell. In the Well_1_Graded_Results column for example I want to retrieve all of the results with a Well_index of 1 from the  TestWell table. Is that more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use logical operators when checking for NULL values. NULL represents unknown, so is 1 = NULL? No. Is 1 <> NULL? No, because NULL *could* be 1 in this case - we don't know, its unknown.

Instead, you need to use  `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` to do NULL checks and comparisons.

So, it would look like this:

`(CASE WHEN tbl_TestWells.well_result IS NOT NULL THEN ...`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have several (6) rows with `tbl_TestWells.Well_Index = 1, 2, 3...` and you want to gather these results in one row?

If yes, you need something like:

```
SELECT
    MIN( CASE WHEN tbl_TestWells.well_result IS NOT NULL
                   AND tbl_TestWells.Well_Index = 1
              THEN tbl_TestWells.well_result
         END
       ) AS  Well_1_Graded_Result
  , MIN( CASE WHEN tbl_TestWells.well_result IS NOT NULL
                  AND tbl_TestWells.Well_Index = 2
              THEN tbl_TestWells.well_result
         END 
       ) AS  Well_2_Graded_Result
  , ...
FROM 
    ...
GROUP BY
         ?                         --- what do these (6) rows have in common?
ORDER BY
         tbl_TestCartridges.barcode
```